# When using a custom rigged and animated model with the XNA 4.0 Skinning example, why does the model animation become deformed?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xnanimation

[Image of the problem below]

The setup:

- Xna 4.0
- Modifying the project example at create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model
- A sample rigged and animated model of a woman from Mixamo in FBX format
- The model is animating, but bones appear to be moving all over the place

I have verified that the model can animate as expected using the Autodesk Converter 2012.2.  So it's not a model, bones or animation issue.

Is this a scale issue? Does a matrix need to be updated?

Full project (40MB) can be downloaded [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25781843/SkinningSample_4_0%20Stack.zip).

[image: (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25781843/ss1.png)]

Comment: If an answer worked for you please accept it. otherwise edit your question or comment on one of the answers

Answer (score 1):

I have tested out your project and the code is fine and works with my models. The problem you are having is in the model itself. Try to export it again, or use a different exporter. I suggest you try 'kw X-port'.